# Ubuntu and OpenVPN

Tags: networking, server, iptables, openvpn

Im trying to setup OpenVPN on Ubuntu and I can't get internet access when I connect. Only local ip of server is reachable (10.8.0.1) Please Help.

My configurations:

**Server.conf**

```
#################################################
# Sample OpenVPN 2.0 config file for            #
# multi-client server.                          #
#                                               #
# This file is for the server side              #
# of a many-clients <-> one-server              #
# OpenVPN configuration.                        #
#                                               #
# OpenVPN also supports                         #
# single-machine <-> single-machine             #
# configurations (See the Examples page         #
# on the web site for more info).               #
#                                               #
# This config should work on Windows            #
# or Linux/BSD systems.  Remember on            #
# Windows to quote pathnames and use            #
# double backslashes, e.g.:                     #
# "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\foo.key" #
#                                               #
# Comments are preceded with '#' or ';'         #
#################################################

# Which local IP address should OpenVPN
# listen on? (optional)
;local a.b.c.d

# Which TCP/UDP port should OpenVPN listen on?
# If you want to run multiple OpenVPN instances
# on the same machine, use a different port
# number for each one.  You will need to
# open up this port on your firewall.
port 1194

# TCP or UDP server?
;proto tcp
proto udp

# "dev tun" will create a routed IP tunnel,
# "dev tap" will create an ethernet tunnel.
# Use "dev tap0" if you are ethernet bridging
# and have precreated a tap0 virtual interface
# and bridged it with your ethernet interface.
# If you want to control access policies
# over the VPN, you must create firewall
# rules for the the TUN/TAP interface.
# On non-Windows systems, you can give
# an explicit unit number, such as tun0.
# On Windows, use "dev-node" for this.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel if you
# have more than one.  On XP SP2 or higher,
# you may need to selectively disable the
# Windows firewall for the TAP adapter.
# Non-Windows systems usually don't need this.
;dev-node MyTap

# SSL/TLS root certificate (ca), certificate
# (cert), and private key (key).  Each client
# and the server must have their own cert and
# key file.  The server and all clients will
# use the same ca file.
#
# See the "easy-rsa" directory for a series
# of scripts for generating RSA certificates
# and private keys.  Remember to use
# a unique Common Name for the server
# and each of the client certificates.
#
# Any X509 key management system can be used.
# OpenVPN can also use a PKCS #12 formatted key file
# (see "pkcs12" directive in man page).
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret

# Diffie hellman parameters.
# Generate your own with:
#   openssl dhparam -out dh1024.pem 1024
# Substitute 2048 for 1024 if you are using
# 2048 bit keys. 
dh dh1024.pem

# Configure server mode and supply a VPN subnet
# for OpenVPN to draw client addresses from.
# The server will take 10.8.0.1 for itself,
# the rest will be made available to clients.
# Each client will be able to reach the server
# on 10.8.0.1. Comment this line out if you are
# ethernet bridging. See the man page for more info.
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

# Maintain a record of client <-> virtual IP address
# associations in this file.  If OpenVPN goes down or
# is restarted, reconnecting clients can be assigned
# the same virtual IP address from the pool that was
# previously assigned.
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging.
# You must first use your OS's bridging capability
# to bridge the TAP interface with the ethernet
# NIC interface.  Then you must manually set the
# IP/netmask on the bridge interface, here we
# assume 10.8.0.4/255.255.255.0.  Finally we
# must set aside an IP range in this subnet
# (start=10.8.0.50 end=10.8.0.100) to allocate
# to connecting clients.  Leave this line commented
# out unless you are ethernet bridging.
;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging
# using a DHCP-proxy, where clients talk
# to the OpenVPN server-side DHCP server
# to receive their IP address allocation
# and DNS server addresses.  You must first use
# your OS's bridging capability to bridge the TAP
# interface with the ethernet NIC interface.
# Note: this mode only works on clients (such as
# Windows), where the client-side TAP adapter is
# bound to a DHCP client.
;server-bridge

# Push routes to the client to allow it
# to reach other private subnets behind
# the server.  Remember that these
# private subnets will also need
# to know to route the OpenVPN client
# address pool (10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0)
# back to the OpenVPN server.
;push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"

# To assign specific IP addresses to specific
# clients or if a connecting client has a private
# subnet behind it that should also have VPN access,
# use the subdirectory "ccd" for client-specific
# configuration files (see man page for more info).

# EXAMPLE: Suppose the client
# having the certificate common name "Thelonious"
# also has a small subnet behind his connecting
# machine, such as 192.168.40.128/255.255.255.248.
# First, uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# Then create a file ccd/Thelonious with this line:
#   iroute 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# This will allow Thelonious' private subnet to
# access the VPN.  This example will only work
# if you are routing, not bridging, i.e. you are
# using "dev tun" and "server" directives.

# EXAMPLE: Suppose you want to give
# Thelonious a fixed VPN IP address of 10.9.0.1.
# First uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.252
# Then add this line to ccd/Thelonious:
#   ifconfig-push 10.9.0.1 10.9.0.2

# Suppose that you want to enable different
# firewall access policies for different groups
# of clients.  There are two methods:
# (1) Run multiple OpenVPN daemons, one for each
#     group, and firewall the TUN/TAP interface
#     for each group/daemon appropriately.
# (2) (Advanced) Create a script to dynamically
#     modify the firewall in response to access
#     from different clients.  See man
#     page for more info on learn-address script.
;learn-address ./script

# If enabled, this directive will configure
# all clients to redirect their default
# network gateway through the VPN, causing
# all IP traffic such as web browsing and
# and DNS lookups to go through the VPN
# (The OpenVPN server machine may need to NAT
# or bridge the TUN/TAP interface to the internet
# in order for this to work properly).
;push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

# Certain Windows-specific network settings
# can be pushed to clients, such as DNS
# or WINS server addresses.  CAVEAT:
# http://openvpn.net/faq.html#dhcpcaveats
# The addresses below refer to the public
# DNS servers provided by opendns.com.
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

# Uncomment this directive to allow different
# clients to be able to "see" each other.
# By default, clients will only see the server.
# To force clients to only see the server, you
# will also need to appropriately firewall the
# server's TUN/TAP interface.
;client-to-client

# Uncomment this directive if multiple clients
# might connect with the same certificate/key
# files or common names.  This is recommended
# only for testing purposes.  For production use,
# each client should have its own certificate/key
# pair.
#
# IF YOU HAVE NOT GENERATED INDIVIDUAL
# CERTIFICATE/KEY PAIRS FOR EACH CLIENT,
# EACH HAVING ITS OWN UNIQUE "COMMON NAME",
# UNCOMMENT THIS LINE OUT.
;duplicate-cn

# The keepalive directive causes ping-like
# messages to be sent back and forth over
# the link so that each side knows when
# the other side has gone down.
# Ping every 10 seconds, assume that remote
# peer is down if no ping received during
# a 120 second time period.
keepalive 10 120

# For extra security beyond that provided
# by SSL/TLS, create an "HMAC firewall"
# to help block DoS attacks and UDP port flooding.
#
# Generate with:
#   openvpn --genkey --secret ta.key
#
# The server and each client must have
# a copy of this key.
# The second parameter should be '0'
# on the server and '1' on the clients.
;tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# This config item must be copied to
# the client config file as well.
;cipher BF-CBC        # Blowfish (default)
;cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES
;cipher DES-EDE3-CBC  # Triple-DES

# Enable compression on the VPN link.
# If you enable it here, you must also
# enable it in the client config file.
comp-lzo

# The maximum number of concurrently connected
# clients we want to allow.
;max-clients 100

# It's a good idea to reduce the OpenVPN
# daemon's privileges after initialization.
#
# You can uncomment this out on
# non-Windows systems.
;user nobody
;group nogroup

# The persist options will try to avoid
# accessing certain resources on restart
# that may no longer be accessible because
# of the privilege downgrade.
persist-key
persist-tun

# Output a short status file showing
# current connections, truncated
# and rewritten every minute.
status openvpn-status.log

# By default, log messages will go to the syslog (or
# on Windows, if running as a service, they will go to
# the "\Program Files\OpenVPN\log" directory).
# Use log or log-append to override this default.
# "log" will truncate the log file on OpenVPN startup,
# while "log-append" will append to it.  Use one
# or the other (but not both).
;log         openvpn.log
;log-append  openvpn.log

# Set the appropriate level of log
# file verbosity.
#
# 0 is silent, except for fatal errors
# 4 is reasonable for general usage
# 5 and 6 can help to debug connection problems
# 9 is extremely verbose
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages.  At most 20
# sequential messages of the same message
# category will be output to the log.
;mute 20

push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

**client.conf**

```
##############################################
# Sample client-side OpenVPN 2.0 config file #
# for connecting to multi-client server.     #
#                                            #
# This configuration can be used by multiple #
# clients, however each client should have   #
# its own cert and key files.                #
#                                            #
# On Windows, you might want to rename this  #
# file so it has a .ovpn extension           #
##############################################

# Specify that we are a client and that we
# will be pulling certain config file directives
# from the server.
client

# Use the same setting as you are using on
# the server.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel
# if you have more than one.  On XP SP2,
# you may need to disable the firewall
# for the TAP adapter.
;dev-node MyTap

# Are we connecting to a TCP or
# UDP server?  Use the same setting as
# on the server.
;proto tcp
proto udp

# The hostname/IP and port of the server.
# You can have multiple remote entries
# to load balance between the servers.
remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 1194
;remote my-server-2 1194

# Choose a random host from the remote
# list for load-balancing.  Otherwise
# try hosts in the order specified.
;remote-random

# Keep trying indefinitely to resolve the
# host name of the OpenVPN server.  Very useful
# on machines which are not permanently connected
# to the internet such as laptops.
resolv-retry infinite

# Most clients don't need to bind to
# a specific local port number.
nobind

# Downgrade privileges after initialization (non-Windows only)
;user nobody
;group nogroup

# Try to preserve some state across restarts.
persist-key
persist-tun

# If you are connecting through an
# HTTP proxy to reach the actual OpenVPN
# server, put the proxy server/IP and
# port number here.  See the man page
# if your proxy server requires
# authentication.
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]

# Wireless networks often produce a lot
# of duplicate packets.  Set this flag
# to silence duplicate packet warnings.
;mute-replay-warnings

# SSL/TLS parms.
# See the server config file for more
# description.  It's best to use
# a separate .crt/.key file pair
# for each client.  A single ca
# file can be used for all clients.
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key

# Verify server certificate by checking
# that the certicate has the nsCertType
# field set to "server".  This is an
# important precaution to protect against
# a potential attack discussed here:
#  http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm
#
# To use this feature, you will need to generate
# your server certificates with the nsCertType
# field set to "server".  The build-key-server
# script in the easy-rsa folder will do this.
ns-cert-type server

# If a tls-auth key is used on the server
# then every client must also have the key.
;tls-auth ta.key 1

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# If the cipher option is used on the server
# then you must also specify it here.
;cipher x

# Enable compression on the VPN link.
# Don't enable this unless it is also
# enabled in the server config file.
comp-lzo

# Set log file verbosity.
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages
;mute 20
```

**iptables -L**

```
root@server:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
AS0_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
AS0_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
AS0_IN_PRE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match 0x2000000/0x2000000
AS0_ACCEPT  udp  --  anywhere             server               state NEW udp dpt:openvpn
AS0_ACCEPT  tcp  --  anywhere             server               state NEW tcp dpt:https
AS0_WEBACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
AS0_WEBACCEPT  tcp  --  anywhere             server               state NEW tcp dpt:943

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
AS0_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
AS0_IN_PRE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match 0x2000000/0x2000000
AS0_OUT_S2C  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.8.0.0/24          anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
AS0_OUT_LOCAL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_ACCEPT (5 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_IN (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             5.5.0.1             
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             localnet/24         
AS0_IN_POST  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_IN_POST (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
AS0_OUT    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_IN_PRE (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
AS0_IN     all  --  anywhere             5.5.0.0/20          
AS0_IN     all  --  anywhere             192.168.0.0/16      
AS0_IN     all  --  anywhere             172.16.0.0/12       
AS0_IN     all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.0/8          
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_OUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_OUT_LOCAL (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp redirect
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_OUT_S2C (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
AS0_OUT    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_WEBACCEPT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

**sysctl.conf**

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

**ifconfig - with openvpn running**

```
root@server:~# ifconfig 
as0t0     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:5.5.0.1  P-t-P:5.5.0.1  Mask:255.255.248.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:200 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:01:6c:2d:be:00  
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::201:6cff:fe2d:be00/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28831661 errors:0 dropped:65539 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25344300 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:27763144851 (27.7 GB)  TX bytes:19771050493 (19.7 GB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:744868 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:744868 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:208557442 (208.5 MB)  TX bytes:208557442 (208.5 MB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5608 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5892 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:1018432 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:4512967 (4.5 MB)
```

**ifconfig - without openvpn running**

```
root@server:~# ifconfig 
as0t0     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:5.5.0.1  P-t-P:5.5.0.1  Mask:255.255.248.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:200 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:01:6c:2d:be:00  
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::201:6cff:fe2d:be00/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28833221 errors:0 dropped:65539 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25345463 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:27763517926 (27.7 GB)  TX bytes:19771192727 (19.7 GB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:744948 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:744948 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:208569802 (208.5 MB)  TX bytes:208569802 (208.5 MB)
```

**netstat -rn - with openvpn running**

```
root@server:~# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
5.5.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U         0 0          0 as0t0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

**netstat -rn - without openvpn running**

```
root@server:~# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
5.5.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U         0 0          0 as0t0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

if anyone can help please do...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenVPN - Linux client could not access internet, routing issue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/845242/openvpn-linux-client-could-not-access-internet-routing-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in routing.
If you have to go on internet via vpn server you must specify route in Server.conf.
Try with default route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 via you_gw_ip

If you have to go on internet from client internet witch already have you must specify route in client.conf.

Do traceroute to any internet address to see where traffic go. On witch interface.

Comment: Where do you mean to set default route? I add it into server.conf:
route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 via 192.168.1.1

if thats what you meant.
traceroute on client side:

cky:~ cky$ traceroute google.si
traceroute: unknown host google.si

Comment: Client can't resolve name, you must specify some dns parameters.

Comment: I see that you put dns in server.conf, but client can't resolve name. Tray traceroute 8.8.8.8 and ping 8.8.8.8

Comment: this is what outputs trace route to 8.8.8.8:

http://pastebin.com/hMEfDeiA

Comment: Ok. That is OK. Network working. Only client can not grab response from dns server and resolve logical name. Traffic go via you gw 192.168.1.1. Try with changing different dns servers [ 8.8.8.8 is google dns server]

Comment: I tried to add dns address like this:

push "dhcp-options 84.255.209.79"
push "dhcp-options 84.255.210.79"

and still no luck (p.s. this are dns addresses from my ISP)

Comment: Hm... Try this. Look for traffic on port 53 [dns] on server.  In the same time on client type host google.com. If client request come to server you will see. If come, fallow on exit interface eth0. Maybe iptables cut some thing

Comment: This is so weird. Now when i disabled ufw it works but only in Google Chrome. When I use Safari it wont work for nothing :) and also in Terminal I cant ping external host. Any ideas?

Comment: No. I don;t have idea what to do.

Comment: I find some info about DNS and vpn connections. Maybe solve problem for you https://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/